# How do I optimize this query that uses a seqscan in postgresql 10.3?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, query-optimization

I have 2 tables in my application

**Unique alerts**

```
asset_id (primary key)
current_price
```

**Alerts**

```
id (primary key)
userid
asset_id (may appear more than once)
alert_price
direction (contains true or false)
```

My Alerts table has 1 million rows and unique alerts table has 40000 rows and I wish to find all the triggered alerts

```
select * from unique_alerts u
INNER JOIN alerts a
ON u.asset_id=a.asset_id
WHERE u.current_price > a.alert_price 
AND a.direction=true
OR u.current_price <= a.alert_price 
AND a.direction=false
```

When I run explain analyze on this query, I see 2 sequential scans, I have an index defined on a.asset_id and it is not being used

```
"Hash Join  (cost=1248.49..34977.79 rows=270686 width=72) (actual time=37.698..713.334 rows=21825 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((a.pair)::text = (u._id)::text)"
"  Join Filter: (((u.current_price > a.alert_price) AND a.direction) OR ((u.current_price <= a.alert_price) AND (NOT a.direction)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 857192"
"  ->  Seq Scan on alerts a  (cost=0.00..20490.00 rows=751170 width=52) (actual time=0.014..158.984 rows=1000000 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (direction OR (NOT direction))"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=711.55..711.55 rows=42955 width=20) (actual time=37.528..37.528 rows=42955 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2766kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on unique_alerts u  (cost=0.00..711.55 rows=42955 width=20) (actual time=0.007..4.891 rows=42955 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.781 ms"
"Execution time: 714.892 ms"
```

How do I ensure the index a.asset_id is being used and what indexes do I need in addition if any? Also if I have to run this join several times, would a view be better? Thanks

Comment: A view doesn't inherently change the execution time.  Think of a view as a macro.  There *are* materialised views, that actually store the results of the query, in effect caching.  Whether this is a good idea depends on how often you read the data and how often you write the data.

Comment: thanks but if had to join this say every 2 mins, wouldnt a view do the join as the inserts happen in both the tables and keep it updated so that i only have to query instead of join everytime, sorry a newbie here in postgres, also if any of the entries are deleted in the 2 tables, do i need a trigger to update the view or does it automatically update itself

Comment: No, a view is effectively just a macro.  A view stores nothing.  A ***materialised*** view is a way to cache the results of the query every time the underlying data changes.  If you read the data significantly more often that you write it, you may see a benefit.  But don't get bogged down in optimisations until you've demonstrated that there really is a problem to be solved.  Premature Optimisation appeals to geeks, but then creates more problems than it solves.  Focus on good engineering first, and optimisation only when absolutely required.

Comment: thanks :) ! i ll definitely keep that sentence in mind "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` is likely making things hard for the optimiser.

One option is to use `UNION ALL` instead to allow two query plans...

```
SELECT * FROM unique_alerts u
INNER JOIN alerts a
ON u.asset_id=a.asset_id
WHERE u.current_price > a.alert_price AND a.direction=true

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM unique_alerts u
INNER JOIN alerts a
ON u.asset_id=a.asset_id
WHERE u.current_price <= a.alert_price AND a.direction=false
```

If you're going to do that, I would recommend a composite index on `alerts` : `(direction, asset_id, alert_price)`

Such an index will make it easier to narrow down the appropriate range of rows.

Comment: @pirateapp - What was the execution time after this change?  *(And have you assessed the impact of the new index on anything that writes data to your table?  You **will** have slowed any write operations down, but hopefully by less than you save by having it.)*

Comment: This takes more time as it involves 2 sequential scans. I also noticed something about the index, the indexes on price values seem redundant as every row will always have different price values, so u.current_price and a.alert_price would be a bad candidate to index, the db size was 82 mb with 1 million rows and the index size was 117 mb with 3 indexes, and naturally the database doesnt use the indexes, i guess pg optimizer is pretty smart to recognize this, btw does the database consider indexes on a.asset_id if it is specified in the join clause, i dont think any other field is indexable

Comment: @PirateApp - Then I suspect that you've created three indexes, where I suggested you create a single index covering three fields?  With a composite index on `(direction, asset_id, alert_price)` the optimiser can eliminate a full half of the index for each query thanks to the `WHERE` clause.  Then the index is further sorted by the asset, which is the principle join predicate, and then sorted by the alert price, allowing a range lookup.  Even though this will still result in two scans, it's scanning half a table and then scanning the other half...

Comment: create index price_index ON alerts (direction, asset_id, alert_price) is a single composite index isnt it? i assume you have call create index 3 times separely which i didnt do